# Very low disk throughput on AWS EBS volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I am currently copying data manually from one EBS volume to another, which has a smaller size, as we have XFS file system, which can not be reduced.

I am using a t3.micro instance (EBS optimised) with Amazon Linux 2 AMI, which has both EBS volumes attached (gp2) additionally to the main from the instance (everything in the same Availability Zone)

I have already done this and it was taking around 5-10 mins to copy 95GB of data (which would be if 10 mins, 162MB/s of throughput), but now, with the same volumes, it is being very slow.

The copying process is:

```
tar cSf - /mnt/nvme1n1p1/ | cat | (cd ../nvme2n1p1/ && tar xSBf -)
```

I have it running in background, and checking at the same time with `iostat -xm 5 3` I am getting this results:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.07    0.02    0.86   39.62    0.05   59.39

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
nvme1n1           0.00     0.00   54.20    0.00     6.70     0.00   253.19     0.94   34.62   34.62    3.56  17.32  93.90
nvme2n1           0.00     0.28    0.06   27.20     0.00     6.71   503.98     0.14    6.67    0.31    6.68   1.22   3.32
nvme0n1           0.00     0.02    2.10    0.90     0.04     0.00    30.65     0.00    0.63    0.63    0.62   0.08   0.02

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.10    0.00    0.70   37.54    0.00   61.66

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
nvme1n1           0.00     0.00   46.40    0.00     5.80     0.00   256.00     1.00   43.16   43.16    0.00  21.48  99.68
nvme2n1           0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
nvme0n1           0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.00    0.00    0.90   38.66    0.10   60.34

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
nvme1n1           0.00     0.00   53.80    0.00     6.73     0.00   256.00     1.00   36.67   36.67    0.00  18.57  99.92
nvme2n1           0.00     0.00    0.00   16.00     0.00     4.00   512.00     0.03    3.20    0.00    3.20   0.80   1.28
nvme0n1           0.00     0.60    0.00    1.40     0.00     0.02    23.14     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

As you can see I am getting a throughput below 10MB/s, and it is going less and less. I have been reading about EBS throughput and I do not find any clue about what can it be, if there is any penality or something similar...

Do you know what it can be?

Thanks in advance! :)

More requested info:

`ulimit -a`:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 3700
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 3700
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

`df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        463M     0  463M   0% /dev
tmpfs           480M     0  480M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           480M  380K  480M   1% /run
tmpfs           480M     0  480M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1  8.0G  1.1G  7.0G  13% /
tmpfs            96M     0   96M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme1n1p1  500G   93G  408G  19% /mnt/nvme1n1p1
/dev/nvme2n1p1  150G   55G   96G  37% /mnt/nvme2n1p1
```

**EBS Burst Balance is +98% all the time.**

**EDIT: it has stopped happening in a new time I have done it**

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com or here.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 4 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report if already available - otherwise skip this request 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits,
iostat -xm 5 3 when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device and core count, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: This looks like the typical behavior encountered when reading from a volume that was recently created from an EBS snapshot.  Does this describe your situation?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot now that you say so, you are probably right. I had to restore the volume from a snapshot because of a mistake, and this time I tried probably was after that! Quite sure! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Open Amazon Cloudwatch and review the “CPUCreditBalance” for the instance. Look at the total credits available with a sample rate of every 5 minutes. Are the credits dropping to near 0 at any point?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-monitoring-cpu-credits.html

A ‘T’ type AWS instance is a burstable,  performance limited type. A t2.micro instance earns only 6 CPU credits per hour. This means your CPU can only run at a sustained 10% usage or it will chew up all of its credits and slow to a crawl.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-monitoring-cpu-credits.html

Increase the size of your instance type. I would recommend changing to a sufficiently sized ‘C’ type instance until after the copy is done. You can downgrade back to a smaller instance afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for replying! CPUCreditBalance has been rising linearly since the beginning. CPU is almos not used at all. It doesn't have to be something about the instance size, RAM usage is less than 60MB, and as I said, with the same instance type, just 2 hours before it was doing it perfectly :(

Comment: EBS volumes also have their own limits and credits based on size. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2019**

Another possible and more likely answer is the instance throughput limit, which have been measured and documented [here](https://cloudonaut.io/ec2-network-performance-cheat-sheet/). A t2.micro has a baseline of 0.06Gbps, which is about 7.5MB/sec, though it can burst to about 10X that.

**EBS Credits**

One possibility is you've run out of EBS credits, which is separate and distinct from the t2/t3 CPU balance. Read [this AWS article about it](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-burst-balance-metric-for-ec2s-general-purpose-ssd-gp2-volumes/).

Add "EBS Burst Balance" for all your volumes to your CloudWatch dashboard. If any are / have been at or near zero that's your answer. If not, keep looking.

Here's part of the documentation I linked to.

> Many AWS customers are getting great results with the General Purpose
>   SSD (gp2) EBS volumes that we launched in mid-2014 (see New SSD-Backed
>   Elastic Block Storage for more information).  If you’re unsure of
>   which volume type to use for your workload, gp2 volumes are the best
>   default choice because they offer balanced price/performance for a
>   wide variety of database, dev and test, and boot volume workloads. One
>   of the more interesting aspects of this volume type is the burst
>   feature.
>
> We designed gp2‘s burst feature to suit the I/O patterns of real world
>   workloads we observed across our customer base. Our data scientists
>   found that volume I/O is extremely bursty, spiking for short periods,
>   with plenty of idle time between bursts. This unpredictable and bursty
>   nature of traffic is why we designed the gp2 burst-bucket to allow
>   even the smallest of volumes to burst up to 3000 IOPS and to replenish
>   their burst bucket during idle times or when performing low levels of
>   I/O. The burst-bucket design allows us to provide consistent  and
>   predictable performance for all gp2 users. In practice, very few gp2
>   volumes ever completely deplete their burst-bucket, and now customers
>   can track their usage patterns and adjust accordingly.
>
> We’ve written extensively about performance optimization across
>   different volume types and the differences between benchmarking and
>   real-world workloads (see I/O Characteristics for more information).
>   As I described in my original post, burst credits accumulate at a rate
>   of 3 per configured GB per second, and each one pays for one read or
>   one write. Each volume can accumulate up to 5.4 million credits, and
>   they can be spent at up to 3,000 per second per volume. To get
>   started, you simply create gp2 volumes of the desired size, launch
>   your application, and your I/O to the volume will proceed as rapidly
>   and efficiently as possible.